# Passing data through mouse events

Tags: c++, mouseevent, wxwidgets, wxgrid

I have a grid set up with a bunch of columns and rows. Right now im able to double click a cell and create a new frame. But I would like to capture the row data on the double click and display that in the new frame. I understand how to create a new frame and display data in it, i just need help in capturing the row data on the double click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was able to achieve this by using GetCellValue(); in wxWidgets.